# WebSphere. SSL. Do I need server certificate to have key encipherment KeyUsage enabled?

Tags: java, ssl, websphere

I'm trying to establish an SSL connection between my client app and WebSphere server. My server certificate supports the following key usages:

> Digital Signature, Certificate Signing, Off-line CRL Signing, CRL
>   Signing

But when I'm trying to connect it throws an exception:

> Initial IOR failed with:
>   CAUGHT_EXCEPTION_WHILE_CONFIGURING_SSL_CLIENT_SOCKET:  JSSL0080E:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException - The client and server could  not
>   negotiate the desired level of security.  Reason: 
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: KeyUsage does not allow key
>   encipherment  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No

So I suppose it wants the `key encipherment`
 key usage enabled. Is there a way to overcome this? If there's no, and SSL requires this key usage enabled, could someone please point me to a reliable specification so that I can convince people who issued my certificate, to re-issue it with this key usage enabled? Do I need the `key agreement` enabled as well?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since the certificate has the "Certificate Signing" key usage, you should probably not use it directly as a server certificate. Instead you should create your own server certificate (with the right key usages for SSL) and sign this certificate using the certificate that was issued to you.

Comment: thank you very much, this is a very interesting option, I will definitely try this.